# To use streams to find keys in a list with max occurance

Tags: java, java-stream

We have a list:

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("10.0 string1", "10.3 string2", "10.0 string3", "10.4 string4","10.3 string5");
```

each entry is a string made of 2 strings separated by space.
Objective is to find all the entries with max number of occurance (i.e 10.0 and 10.3 wit 2 occurrences).

The following code works. Question is could these 3 statements be reduced to 1 or at least 2?

```
var map2 = strList.stream()
                  .map(m -> {String[] parts = m.split(" "); return parts[0];})
                  .collect((Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting())));

var max3 = map2.entrySet().stream()
               .max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1) 
               .get() 
               .getValue();

var listOfMax2 = map2.entrySet().stream()
                     .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == max3)
                     .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(listOfMax2);
```

Comment: correction:         var max3 = map1.entrySet().stream()
                .max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1)
                .get()
                .getValue();

Comment: Note: `.max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`

Comment: correction2: sorry in above correction, map1 should be map2

Comment: @sid Please use the edit button to edit your question directly instead of adding comments. For now I have edited already, feel free to edit it again if there are any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is pretty straight forward if you change the names of your variables to something meaningfull. You could write a custom collector, but i doubt it is worth the effort and is able to make your code much more readable. The easiest solution I can think of is, if you insists in chaining your stream, to first build the frequency and then invert the map to use the values(frequencies) as key and keys as value and to collect to a Treemap, which is sorted by key, and get the last entry:

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("10.0 string1", "10.3 string2", "10.0 string3", "10.4 string4", "10.3 string5");

var mostFrequentEntries =
        strList.stream()
               .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' ')))
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
               .entrySet()
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
               .lastEntry().getValue();

System.out.println(mostFrequentEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

This simplest way I know is to start with a frequency count of for the targeted value and return the maximum value and the map in a data structure for subsequent processing.

Here is some data (added to yours for demo)

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("10.0 string1",
        "10.0 string2", "10.3 string3", "10.0 string4",
        "10.3 string5", "10.4 string6", "10.3 string7",
        "10.4 string8", "10.5 string9", "10.6 string10");
```

- first, stream the list and create a map based on frequency. This is done via using `toMap` and incrementing the count for duplicate keys.
- then stream the entries of that map looking for the maximum count.  Then return the count and the map in a `SimpleEntry` data structure.

```
Entry<Integer,Map<String,Integer>> result =  strList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(str -> str.split("\\s+")[0],, s -> 1,Integer::sum),
                     m -> new SimpleEntry<>(
                      m.isEmpty() ? 0 : Collections.max(m.values()),m)));
```

- Now, using the returned map and the maximum count, print all the keys that have the same count.

```
int max = result.getKey();
result.getValue().forEach((k,v)-> {
    if (v == max) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
});
```

prints

```
10.4
10.3
10.0
```

Thanks to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) for making some suggestions regarding `Collections.max` and the two argument version of `String.split()`.